# How to route traffic from a subnet 10.0.0.x to a network 200.208.88.17

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, routing

I have the following configuration

```
Router       : IP:   200.208.88.17  (Internet)
               MASK: 255.255.255.40


Server 2003  : IP:  10.0.0.1 (with dhcp server ativated) dhcp scope: 10.0.0.11 - 10.0.0.254
               MASK: 255.255.255.0 

clients      : IP: 10.0.0.11 - 10.0.0.254
               MASK: 255.255.255.0
```

At this point I have all computer set-up in one switch. All clients are receiving ip´s from the dhcp server. I need to enable the internet in every client.
I am not sure how to route the traffic from the clients to the router that is providing internet access.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to route from one network to another, your router should have an interface in both networks. For instance, it could have the IP address 10.0.0.2 in your case. Then, you would configure your DHCP server to [provide your clients with a default gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941211(v=ws.10).aspx) to 10.0.0.2. When your clients will want to reach a network outside 10.0.0.0/24, they'll send the packets to your router. Also, you'll need to [setup NAT](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094e77.shtml) so that traffic going on the WAN interface all appear to come from your public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you must do something call `NAT`, not `Route`. Because you had a router, so it must have at least two interface to work probably.

The first interface has IP `200.208.88.17`, the second's IP is one in range `10.0.0.2` to `10.0.0.10`. Then you will config DHCP server to make client default gateway point to Router's second interface.

Finally, config `NAT Overload` in your router, then all client can access Internet at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a *default gateway* in your DHCP configuration, and set it to the LAN IP of your router. This will let your DHCP clients route all packets not in their subnet to your router, which will then forward them out to the Internet. You should be able to add your default gateway by following the instructions on this guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756865(v=ws.10).aspx

As mentioned in another answer, your router will then (normally without any configuration) apply SNAT (Source Network Address Translation) so that all packets originating from within your network will appear to be from its WAN interface.

Note that SNAT is different from Destinatin Network Address Translation (DNAT). DNAT is the most common form of NAT, and confusingly this is what most people refer to when using the term NAT. DNAT alters the destination of the packets (often called port forwarding), whereas SNAT alters the packets' source headers.